jsPDF issue while open pdf after download
 const div3PDF = (e) => {
        setLoading(true);
        let input = window.document.getElementsByClassName("div3PDF")[0];

        html2canvas(input, {
            scale: 3, // Increase the scale for higher resolution
            useCORS: true,
            logging: true,
            backgroundColor: null // Ensure background is captured correctly
        }).then((canvas) => {
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

            // Calculate PDF dimensions with extra space
            const margin = 20;
            const pdfWidth = canvas.width * 0.75 + 2 * margin; // Convert canvas width to points (1pt = 0.75px)
            const pdfHeight = canvas.height * (pdfWidth / canvas.width) + 2 * margin;

            // Create PDF with extra space
            const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", [pdfWidth, pdfHeight], true); // "pt" for points

            // Add image with space around
            pdf.addImage(
                imgData,
                "PNG",
                margin, margin, // Position of the image with extra space around
                canvas.width * 0.75, canvas.height * 0.75 // Dimensions of the image in the PDF
            );

            // Save PDF
            pdf.save("chart.pdf");
            setLoading(false);
            toast.success("PDF Downloaded Successfully.");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

above is my code i facing issue while open pdf and appears all mixed rainbow colors on pdf with scale is 5. If i set scale 2 then working fine.
provide better solution with scale 5 and pdf looks proper with high quality and all rainbow colors disappear from downloaded pdf
